# How to sed a block of text with specific pattern?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have file looking like this

```
...
%pythons
Albino
Black Bee
Bumble Bee
%end

%boa
Albino
Jungle
Pastel
%end
...
```

I would like to sed one whole block from this file matching pattern for saving or sustitution purposes.Number of lines in a block may very. I need common solution.
I'm looking for something like this

```
sed -n '/^%boa(**something here**)^%end$//p' snakes > boa
sed 's/^%boa(**something here**)^%end$/(**new block**)/' snakes > snakes_updated
```

I'm looking specifically for sed solution. Any suggestions with explanation would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to delete a block or do you want only the block?

Comment: i need save this block to another file or substitute it with another block if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -e '/%boa/,/%end/{w fileb' -e '/%end/!d;r filec' -e 'd}' filea
```

This writes the section between `%boa` and `%end` to fileb and replaces it with the contents of filec. The contents of filea is replaced by the edited operations by using the `-i` flag.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you can do it [grouping commands](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-35) in this way:

```
sed -i.bak '/^%boa/,/%end/ {
    wboas
    d
}' file
```

With the [`w` command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-36) you're writing the content between the [addresses](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-25) `/^%boa/,/%end/` to the file **boas**.
With the [`d` command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-30), you're deleting those lines in the original file (with the help of the [`-i` option](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-62h)).

Original file:

```
$ cat file
...
%pythons
Albino
Black Bee
Bumble Bee
%end

%boa
Albino
Jungle
Pastel
%end
...
```

#### Example

```
$ sed -i.bak '/^%boa/,/%end/ {
>     wboas
>     d
> }' file

$ cat boas
%boa
Albino
Jungle
Pastel
%end

$ cat file
...
%pythons
Albino
Black Bee
Bumble Bee
%end

...
```

---

In addition, if you need to substitute the block with something else (let's say `"hello\n    world"`), you can append it with the [`a` command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-40):

```
sed -i.bak '/^%boa/,/%end/ {
    wboas
    /^%boa/a \
    hello \
    world
    d
}' file
```

#### Example

```
$ sed -i.bak '/^%boa/,/%end/ {
>     wboas
>     /^%boa/a \
>     hello \
>     world
>     d
> }' file

$ cat file
...
%pythons
Albino
Black Bee
Bumble Bee
%end

    hello 
    world
...

$ cat boas
%boa
Albino
Jungle
Pastel
%end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
$ sed -n '/^%boa$/,/^%end$/p' file
%boa
Albino
Jungle
Pastel
%end
```

It print the lines which falls within a specific range.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to substitute such block with this pattern to another block of text? using sed 's/pattern/block/' file ?

Comment: to save the block to another file `sed -n '/^%boa$/,/^%end$/p' infile > outfile` but i don't know how to do a block substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl -0` you can easily search and replace one block from this file:

```
perl -0pe 's~(?ms)\R%boa.*%end(\R|\z)~\n---\nfoo\nbar\nbaz\n---\n~' file
...
%pythons
Albino
Black Bee
Bumble Bee
%end

---
foo
bar
baz
---
...
```