# Add a block of text after another with sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I want to add the following block of text 
    //There are more text here
    zone "mysite.com" {
     type master;
     file "mysite.com.fwd";
     allow-update { none; };
     };

just after the block of text shown below

```
zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};
```

The file should ultimately look like the following

```
 //There are more lines up here
 zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
    };

  zone "mysite.com" {
       type master;
       file "mysite.com.fwd";
         allow-update { none; };
         };
            //There are more lines below here
```

The difficult here is that `\n` in the pattern to match don't work with sed.

Thanks for your help in advanced

Comment: This SO question might be helpful: [SED - Regular Expression over multiple lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510813/sed-regular-expression-over-multiple-lines)

Comment: @lucker It is helpful but i am looking to append data here.Post as an answer

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
sed "/^};/a \ \nzone \"mysite.com\" {\n type master;\n file \"mysite.com.fwd\";\n allow-update { none; };\n};\n" test.conf
```

Before

```
zone "." IN {
 type hint;
 file "named.ca";
};
```

After

```
zone "." IN {
 type hint;
 file "named.ca";
};

zone "mysite.com" {
 type master;
 file "mysite.com.fwd";
 allow-update { none; };
};
```

`^};` is a pattern here after which you append your new block using `a`, you can change pattern if you need it.

Another approach with sed which is more flexible - using file, in which you have new block:

```
sed "/^};/r block.conf" test.conf
```

Here we just add text from `block.conf` to `test.conf` using read command `r`. `/^};/` once again your pattern.

This range pattern should be uniqe `/file \"named.ca\";/,/^};/` i guess so this should work for you pretty much

```
sed "/file \"named.ca\";/,/^};/ {
/file*/n
a \ \nzone \"mysite.com\" {\n type master;\n file \"mysite.com.fwd\";\n allow-update { none; };\n};\n
}
" test.conf
```

`//,//` structure represents ranged pattern starting from line with appropriate pattern and ending with another. In our case it's 2 lines pattern and we want to skip first line, here comes `/file*/n`. And then we append our block at the and of second line starting from blank line.

Some useful approaches is also here: [How to sed a block of text with specific pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408626/how-to-sed-a-block-of-text-with-specific-pattern?rq=1)

Comment: Its actually the reverse the `zone "." IN` is what was in the file before and the `zone "mysite.com"` is what need to be added.Kindly edit your answer.Thanks

Comment: There is  text before `zone "." IN`(so its no the beginning of the file.Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: if you have more text like this }; you just need another pattern to use. And your new block will be appended after the pattern. But you have to come up with uniqe pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is not a good tool for it. it's way simple to do it in shell:

```
cat file1 >> file2
```

it means append content in `file1` to the end of `file2`.

UPDATE:

```
sed -e '$r file1' file2 > file2
```

would work.

still don't get why `sed` is safer than shell though.

Comment: The problem is that there are some lines after you add the block

Comment: @user2650277 why not adding more `cat`? or use `sed` after? what's the restriction?

Comment: its a configuration file (named.conf) and i can't afford to break things .sed is safest in this situation

Comment: We haven't reach the end of file yet , there are more text below the `zone "mysite.com"` zone and more text before the `zone "." IN`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr As you see OP says I want to add block of text after a specific block and he has another lines after that block. See last line of his posted output `//There are more lines below here` and also has a lines before the block in first line mentioned `//There are more lines up here`

Comment: @KasiyA i know. the subtle part is the OP wants `sed` only. it's pain in the ass if a not handy tool is a must. according to these few lines, i would say coding up a format specific parser and using shell to wrap it is a better solution full of advantages. but it seems OP won't be happy to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a proper & robust solution, there's some [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s modules to parse bind8 config file.

Check [Unix::Conf::Bind8::Conf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unix::Conf::Bind8::Conf)

Answer (score 0):

Asumming the following codes are in "my_file" and substituting "^" in the place of new line characters to get one big line. We can now match the pattern `"file "named.ca";` and then substitue the new codes after this. Afterwards you convert "^" back to newline chars "\n".

```
cat 'my_file'|tr '\n' '^'|sed 's#//There are more lines up here- zone.*\(file "named.ca"\).*#\1  zone "mysite.com" {\n        type master;\n        file "mysite.com.fwd";\n            allow-update { none; }; };\n#g'|tr '^' '\n'
```

Results

```
//There are more lines up here
 zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
    };

  zone "mysite.com" {
       type master;
       file "mysite.com.fwd";
         allow-update { none; };
         };
            //There are more lines below here
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any of these to work on MacOS.

This works for me:

```
sed -i '' "/^\s*};/ a \\
\\
\zone "mysite.com" {\\
\  type master;\\
\  file "mysite.com.fwd";\\
\  allow-update { none; };\\
\};\\
" filename
```

This is tested with the following script. It creates a new file, prints it out, modifies it and prints it again:

```
testfile="testsed.txt"
rm ${testfile}
cat <<EOF > ${testfile}
//There are more lines up here
zone "." IN {
  type hint;
  file "named.ca";
};
EOF
cat ${testfile}

sed -i '' "/^\s*};/ a \\
\\
\zone "mysite.com" {\\
\  type master;\\
\  file "mysite.com.fwd";\\
\  allow-update { none; };\\
\};\\
" ${testfile}

echo
echo "==== After Transform ===="
echo
cat ${testfile}
```